WinEdt11 macro replace problem
I want to perform 5 replacements using a WinEdt11 macro, but after the first replacement, an info window pops up, stating the number of replacements made, and it stops the macro. How can I prevent this info window from appearing?
Sample:
GoToBeginningOfFile;
SearchReset;
SetSearchCurrentDoc;
SetSearchRelaxed(0);
SetSearchInline(0);
SetSearchCurrentDoc;
SetSearchCyclic(0);
SetSearchEntire(0);
SetReplacePrompt(0);
SetSearchCaseSensitive(1);
SetSearchForward(1);
SetSearchWholeWords(1);
SetReplaceRespectCaps(1);
SetFindQuickReplace(1);
SetRegEx(1);
SetFindStr("\\DicsElso");
SetReplaceStr("\\textbf\{Első dicséretben részesül:\}\\enspace\\ignorespaces");
SetTracking(0);
SetOK(1);
ReplaceAll;
SetTracking(1);
GoToBeginningOfFile;
SearchReset;
SetFindStr("\\DicsMasik");
SetReplaceStr("\\textbf\{Második dicséretben részesül:\}\\enspace\\ignorespaces");
SetTracking(0);
SetOK(1);
ReplaceAll;
SetTracking(1);
GoToBeginningOfFile;
...


Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you considered posting your query to winedt.org, the site of the winedt community?

Add SetReplaceNotify(0); before SetFindStr("\\DicsElso");.
Here is the usage of SetReplaceNotify in the WinEdt help file.


Please explain better!
